# how to use PDO connection object in different files

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

Hello i am new to PDO with MYSQL, here are my two files
 **1) index.php**

```
require_once 'prd.php';
try{
    $db = new PDO ('mysql:host=xxxx;dbname=xxx;charset=utf8', 'xxx', 'xxxx');
    echo 'connectd';
}catch(PDOException $conError){
    echo 'failed to connect DB' . $conError->getMessage ();
}
$conn = new prdinfo();
$conn->con($db);
```

**2) product.php**

```
class prdinfo{function con($db){
    try{
        foreach($db->query("select * from products where vendor_id = 2" ) as $row){
            $prod_id = $row ['product_id'];
            echo '<br/>' . $prod_id;
        }
    }catch(PDOException $ex){
        echo 'an error occured' . $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
}
```

my problem is here i can pass the connection object to every file, but  i have so many files to use database queries, so i need to pass the $bd to all the files. this is getting burden on the code. so is there any way to connect the database with PDO.
**Thanks**

Answer (score 5):

1. `pdo.php`, taken from [here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql). People often overlook many important connection options, so I had to write a dedicated article that explains how to connect with PDO properly
2. `product.php`

   ```
    <?php
    class prdinfo  
    { 
        function __construct($db)
        {
            $this->db = $db;
        }

        function getVendor($vendor)
        {
            $sql = "select * from products where vendor_id = ?";
            $stm = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stm->execute(array($vendor));
            return $stm->fetchAll();
        }
    }
   ```
3. `index.php`

   ```
    <?php
    require 'pdo.php';
    require 'product.php';

    $info   = new prdinfo($pdo);
    $vendor = $info->getVendor(2);
    foreach ($vendor as $row)
    {
        echo $row['product_id'];
    }
   ```

It would be also a good idea to implement class autoloading instead of manually calling require.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way of doing it is to do the database connectivity in a separate file like "database.php and then you can include this file on every new page you are creating...eg if you are creating a page like "dothis.php". then at the top of your dothis.php page write a statement `include_once ('/path/to/your/file/database.php');`
then you can use your `$db` object in the whole file wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a PHP file, let's say 'pdoconn.php'. In that file, prepare that `$db` object. Finally, for each of your PHP files, just include `pdoconn.php` at first. So, while your PHP files are being loaded, they will firstly connect to MySQL and give you the `$db` object.